# How can I migrate Mbox emails to new version of Evolution?

Tags: email, evolution, mail

How can I convert my old Mbox emails so that I can read them in the new version of Evolution?

I am using Evolution 3.10.4 under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I cannot read my previous Evolution emails, following Evolution's conversion from Mbox to Maildir.

The emails appear to have been placed in a "cur" folder under "local_mbox".

When from within Evolution I click on an email folder, I get the message "Failed to open folder. The reported error was 'Cannot get folder 'cur/': folder does not exist."
[Error message on attempting to open email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqhRJ.png)

The problem occurred when Evolution provided a message, "Evolution's local mail format has changed. Evolution's local mail format has changed from mbox to Maildir. Your local main must be migrated to the nre format before Evolution can proceed. Do you want to migrate now? An mbox account will be created to preserve the old mbox folders. You can delete the account after ensuring the data is safely migrated. Please make sure there is enough disk space if you choose to migrate."
[Evolution mail format change message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsDqL.png)